# Using a class function as callback

Tags: gpio, python

I want to set a callback function to run when an event occurs in a GPIO. I'm designing a class and I want to have the callback method inside it too. Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

class WheelEncoder:
  'Encapsulates the attributes and methods to use a wheel encoder sensor'

  inputPin = 0
  ticks = 0

  def __init__(self, inputPin):
    self.inputPin = inputPin

    gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
    gpio.setup(self.inputPin, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_UP)
    gpio.add_event_detect(self.inputPin, gpio.RISING, event_callback)

  def getTicks(self):
    return self.ticks

  def resetTicks(self):
    self.ticks = 0

  def event_callback(channel):
    self.ticks += 1
```

And here is the output of calling it (from another file):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-WheelEncoder.py", line 5, in <module>
    sensor = WheelEncoder(3, 10, 3)
  File "/home/pi/codes/sensors/WheelEncoder.py", line 20, in __init__
    gpio.add_event_detect(self.inputPin, gpio.RISING, event_callback)
NameError: global name 'event_callback' is not defined
```

Im not sure what it could be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found the answer. I changed the call to `add_event_detect` to be

```
gpio.add_event_detect(self.inputPin, gpio.RISING, self.event_callback)
```

and changed the signature of `event_callback` to be

```
event_callback(self, channel):
```

The complete code can be seen in my own repository: https://github.com/luizfzs/python-pi-sensor-modules/blob/master/WheelEncoder.py#L28